# Can I associate an image with a class and load this image without creating an instance of the class?

Tags: image, attributes, c#-2.0

Long time lurker, first time poster here.

My question is:

Using C# 2.0, is there a way to associate am image with a class/type such that I don't have to create an instance of the class just to get the image object from that class?

What I am trying to do is scan all the .dlls in my application and construct a list of classes and corresponding attributes. I have this working great, and now I want to somehow associate an image with each class so that I can display a list of classes and have a unique image for each.

I've tried searching SO and the internet for an answer, but can't find anything definite. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it using ideas here and there.

1. Mark the image as an EmbeddedResource.
2. Create an attribute for specifying the image name.
3. Once the image name attribute is read, use the following to locate the image resource inside the assembly where the class was declared:

   ```
   string[] all = info.Type.Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

   foreach (string resourceStr in all)
   {
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceStr) && resourceStr.EndsWith(String.Format(".{0}", iconName), true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
     {
       Stream file = info.Type.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceStr);

       if (file != null)
       {
         info.Icon = Image.FromStream(file);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an ImageAttribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
class ImageAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string ImagePath { get; set; } 

    public ImageAttribute(string imagePath)
    {
        ImagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public Bitmap Image
    {
        get { return new Bitmap(ImagePath); }
    }
}
```

Or database id, just some way to identify an image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I understand your solution, only problem is that my images are currently added to a resource file in each of the projects. Is there a way I can get the file path if all I know about the image is how to access it through the resource file like "Properties.Resources.MyImage"?

Comment: Well then it would just be the general way to get out a compiled resource. You could pass along the name of the compiled resource. I've done something similar in the past, but don't have the code for it anymore.